# Adult Edition Online Community

Tags: small-communities, adult-content

I'm starting a new online art and entertainment website but I'm facing an censorship issue.

As the site is art orientated, and of a certain niche ( not `"adult"` ), it is a certainty that from time to time I will be featuring content that is for the eyes of over 18's only, and therefore should really be in a section of it's own. That being said, I don't really want to contfine certian posts to a side area when the content is certainly on-topic, and not `Adult` in the popular sense of the word.

Not sure if I'm supposed to place links, but check out this https://www.magcloud.com/browse/issue/1406783 magazine for an idea of what my dilema is.

Here, there is an emphasis on music ( entertainment for all ages ), but features of semi-nude models ( appealing to many music fans, but not for under 18 viewing ).

So my general idea is to place a `18` certificate icon on the link to any page that has content of an adult nature - But I still feel that it will be too easy for a younger audience to click these links.

For clarification, I don't want to brand my community as `Adults Only`, because that gives out the wrong impression - And, I would prefer not to have to market/brand my community twice ( all ages / over 18 ).

Any ideas how I should go about keeping my site open to showcasing All types of content, but still keeping it clean?

Answer (score 1):

How about displaying 18+ content only to users that have checked a checkbox stating they were born at least 18 years ago?